# What's the correct usage of Friend's bcrypt-credential-fn?

Tags: web-applications, clojure, compojure

I'm building a simple practice web-app, working on login with friend, and am trying to transition from the tutorial examples dummy in-memory database to accessing my DynamoDB database.

```
(handler/site
(friend/authenticate app{
                     :login-uri "/login"
                     :unauthorized-redirect-uri "/login"
                     :credential-fn (partial creds/bcrypt-credential-fn users)
                     :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})))

(defn users
[uname]
(read-string (get-in (db/valid-user? uname "UB") [:item :friend-map])))
```

The problem arises with my users function, my understanding(and this could very likely be where I'm wrong) reading the friend source-code is that bcrypt-credentials-fn calls the next function with an argument of the username provided from the /login. Examples/tutorials I've seen around seem follow that pattern.

If I call users with a username like, "bob@bob.bob", it returns a hash-map with friend credentials

```
{"bob@bob.bob" {:username "bob@bob.bob", 
              :password "$2a$10$rtDxqCqZRIRFFzjCYD9d.uiQ2NuUMXto.jCbWNPtVKF1y/d4WPL/C",          
              :roles #{:practice.models.db/admin}}}
```

If I hard-code a username into the users function, it works fine and I can log in with it, but when replacing it with uname, or (str uname), just to make sure it's a string. I get a null-pointer exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
BCrypt.java:663 org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.hashpw
BCrypt.java:763 org.mindrot.jbcrypt.BCrypt.checkpw
credentials.clj:18  cemerick.friend.credentials/bcrypt-verify
credentials.clj:47  cemerick.friend.credentials/bcrypt-credential-fn
AFn.java:163    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper
AFn.java:151    clojure.lang.AFn.applyTo
core.clj:619    clojure.core/apply
core.clj:2396   clojure.core/partial[fn]
RestFn.java:408 clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke
workflows.clj:80    cemerick.friend.workflows/interactive-form[fn]
friend.clj:180  cemerick.friend/authenticate*[fn]
core.clj:2485   clojure.core/map[fn]
LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
LazySeq.java:60 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
RT.java:484 clojure.lang.RT.seq
core.clj:133    clojure.core/seq
core.clj:2523   clojure.core/filter[fn]
LazySeq.java:42 clojure.lang.LazySeq.sval
LazySeq.java:60 clojure.lang.LazySeq.seq
LazySeq.java:82 clojure.lang.LazySeq.first
RT.java:577 clojure.lang.RT.first
core.clj:55 clojure.core/first
friend.clj:180  cemerick.friend/authenticate*
friend.clj:208  cemerick.friend/authenticate[fn]
keyword_params.clj:32   ring.middleware.keyword-params/wrap-keyword-params[fn]
nested_params.clj:70    ring.middleware.nested-params/wrap-nested-params[fn]
params.clj:58   ring.middleware.params/wrap-params[fn]
multipart_params.clj:106    ring.middleware.multipart-params/wrap-multipart-params[fn]
flash.clj:31    ring.middleware.flash/wrap-flash[fn]
session.clj:85  ring.middleware.session/wrap-session[fn]
resource.clj:24 ring.middleware.resource/wrap-resource[fn]
file_info.clj:63    ring.middleware.file-info/wrap-file-info[fn]
middleware.clj:12   hiccup.middleware/wrap-base-url[fn]
Var.java:415    clojure.lang.Var.invoke
reload.clj:18   ring.middleware.reload/wrap-reload[fn]
stacktrace.clj:15   ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-log[fn]
stacktrace.clj:79   ring.middleware.stacktrace/wrap-stacktrace-web[fn]
jetty.clj:18    ring.adapter.jetty/proxy-handler[fn]
(Unknown Source)                                         
ring.adapter.jetty.proxy$org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler$0.handle
HandlerWrapper.java:111 org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle
Server.java:349 org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle
AbstractHttpConnection.java:452 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest
AbstractHttpConnection.java:894 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.content
AbstractHttpConnection.java:948    
org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.content
HttpParser.java:857 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext
HttpParser.java:235 org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable
AsyncHttpConnection.java:76 org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle
SelectChannelEndPoint.java:609  org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle
SelectChannelEndPoint.java:45   org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run
QueuedThreadPool.java:599   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob
QueuedThreadPool.java:534   org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run
Thread.java:722 java.lang.Thread.run
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I figured it out.

My mistake was taking the example data a bit too literally.

bcrypt-credntials-fn is looking for :username in hash-map returned from the function it calls, which means my credentials map was nested one too deep. This works in my example.

```
{:username "bob@bob.bob", 
          :password "$2a$10$rtDxqCqZRIRFFzjCYD9d.uiQ2NuUMXto.jCbWNPtVKF1y/d4WPL/C",          
          :roles #{:practice.models.db/admin}}
```

It'd work hard-coding it because it'd look for essentially ["bob@bob.bob" :username], which is valid.

Hope this helps anyone else having same issue.

Comment: I made the same false assumption and I solved my issue by reading your question and answer.  So thanks a lot for asking it!

Answer (score 0):

```
(def page (handler/site
            (friend/authenticate
              routes
              {:allow-anon? true
               :login-uri "/login"
               :default-landing-uri "/"
               :unauthorized-handler #(-> (h/html5
                                           misc/head
                                             (misc/body [:h3 "You do not have sufficient privileges to access " (:uri %)]
                                                   [:a {:class "button secondary" :href "/interactive_form"} "Main"]))
                                        resp/response
                                        (resp/status 401))
               ;:credential-fn #(creds/bcrypt-credential-fn @users %)
               :credential-fn #(creds/bcrypt-credential-fn db/get-user %)
               :workflows [(workflows/interactive-form)]})))
```

...

```
(ns myapp.models.db
  (:require [clojure.java.jdbc :as sql])
  (:import java.sql.DriverManager))

(def db {:classname "org.sqlite.JDBC",
         :subprotocol "sqlite",
         :subname "db.sq1"})

(defn create-user-table []
  (sql/with-connection
    db
      (sql/create-table
        :userstable
        [:username "varchar(20) PRIMARY KEY"]
        [:password "varchar(100)"]
        [:email "varchar(100)"]
        [:balance "float"]
        [:roles "boolean"])))

(defn add-user-record [user]
  (if-not (.exists (java.io.File. "./db.sq1"))
    (create-user-table))

  (sql/with-connection db
  (sql/insert-record :userstable user)))

(defn get-user [name]
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results
      res ["select * from userstable where username = ?" name] (first res))))
```

...
Also let users in users.clj as it is